# Comment exprimer un évènement futur soumis à une condition ?

Tags: conditionnel, futur

J'aimerai dire une phrase similaire à

> En supposant que j'aurai un téléphone quand je rentrerai, je t'appellerai

en utilisant le conditionnel. Cela donnerait quelque chose comme

> Si j'aurai un téléphone, je t'appellerais

Cette phrase ne me paraît pas bonne, alors il y a-t-il une façon correcte d'exprimer le futur sous condition ?

Comment: En supposant que j'aie un téléphone quand je rentrerai, je t'appellerai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Au futur, on n'utilise pas le conditionnel mais l'indicatif pour les événements soumis à une condition :

> Si j'ai un téléphone, je t'appeller**ai**.

La condition se construit au présent, indicatif ou subjonctif selon la conjonction de subordination. Par exemple dans ceux que tu cites, "si" est suivi de l'indicatif et "en supposant que", du subjonctif.

> Si je **peux** trouver un téléphone, je t'appellerai.
>
> En supposant que je **puisse** trouver un téléphone, je t'appellerai.

*(je n'ai pas facilement accès à des sources actuellement, je les ajouterai plus tard ou bien n'hésitez pas à éditer mon message)*